# getting a parent node and its child, where the child has a certain text

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am trying to retrieve a parent node and it's child, where the child has a certain text.

this is my html:

```
<bod>
    <div>
         <span>something</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

i am using the following to catch the child :

```
 $the_child = $xpath->query('(//*[text()[contains(., "something")]])[1]');
```

but how do i also catch his first parent ?

Comment: See a pure XPath solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the item, just get its `->parentNode` property.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure XPath solution:**

```
(//*[*[contains(., 'something')]])[1] | (//*/*[contains(., 'something')])[1]
```