# XPath finding certain node with certain text

Tags: php, html, xpath

So I had a question regarding something similar to that at:

[getting a parent node and its child, where the child has a certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007344/getting-a-parent-node-and-its-child-where-the-child-has-a-certain-text)

But the situation change and I find some problems with my above idea.
I am now trying to find a node with specific text because it seems when I use 29 it will also find nodes that has 2999 or anything else that has 29 in it.

So my question is how can I turn :

`$myvar = $xpath->query('(//*[text()[contains(., "something")]])');`

so it will look for node with certain text. not for a node that "has" certain text.

Comment: Please post the test data, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `//*[text() = "29"]` instead of `contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//*[. = 29]
```

This selects any element, whose string value, when converted to a number is equal to 29.