# xpath finding out what child number is amongst other siblings

Tags: php, html, xpath

I've had several other question related to the subject:

[getting a parent node and its child, where the child has a certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007344/getting-a-parent-node-and-its-child-where-the-child-has-a-certain-text)

and 
[XPath finding certain node with certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012564/xpath-finding-certain-node-with-certain-text)

Lets say this is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
          <span>something else</span>
          <span>something</span>
          <span>something else</span>
    <div>
</body>
```

I am using the following to query for a node with certain text:

`$node_with_value = $xpath->query('(//*[text()= "'something"])');`

this returns the list with all node that has something.
In this case it will be only 1.

to find its parent i do:
`parent = $node_with_value->item(0)->parentNode;`

Now my question is how can i check what number of child it is.

in the above we have 3 span children to the div, counting from top to bottom its number 2. is there a way to count that programmaticaly?

Comment: You just need to get the number of children that the parent of you matched child has, and the loop over them incrementally until your matched child

Comment: I thought of doing a `foreach` children and search for the text until i find the right child however i dont know how to access the childrens.  like accessing attribute it would be $node->attributes. how do i access its children ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath you can do `$count = $xpath->evaluate("count(. | preceding-sibling::*)", $node-with-value->item(0))` to find the number in terms of sibling elements or `$count = $xpath->evaluate("count(. | preceding-sibling::node())", $node-with-value->item(0))` to find the number in terms of sibling nodes (i.e. element nodes but text, comment and processing instruction nodes as well).

Answer (score 0):

**Again a pure XPath solution**:

```
count(/*/*/span[.='something']/preceding-sibling::*) +1
```